# Select rows where at least X columns matches condition pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame df

```
0 0 1 1 2  
0 0 1 2 2
```

How do I select rows where at least 2 columns have value > 1? So, only select the second row in the df above

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`gt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.gt.html) with [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) along `axis=1` as:

```
df[df.gt(1).sum(axis=1).gt(1)]
```

Or:

```
df[(df>1).sum(axis=1)>1]
```